# Cache Eloquent Relationship query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How can I cache this Eloquent query:

```
dd($user->roles);
```

Because above will somehow trigger the `$user->roles()` query I assume.

I have tried with this:

```
    public function roles() {
        return \Cache::remember('user_' . $this->id . '_roles', 10, function() {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Role');
        });
    }
```

But it does not work, because it has to return a array, not eloquent query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching? It may do what you need. Full disclosure: this is a package I wrote.

Answer (score 33):

Here is an approach updated for modern Laravel:

```php
// Define your relation
public function bookmarks(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bookmark::class);
}

// Define the cache key (as its used in multiple places)
protected function getBookmarksCacheKey(): string
{
    return sprintf('user-%d-bookmarks', $this->id);
}

// Provide a cache clearing mechanism
public function clearBookmarksCache(): bool
{
    return Cache::forget($this->getBookmarksCacheKey());
}

// Override the relation property getter
// It will return the cached collection when it exists, otherwise getting a fresh one from the database
// It then populates the relation with that collection for use elsewhere
public function getBookmarksAttribute(): Collection
{
    // If the relation is already loaded and set to the current instance of model, return it
    if ($this->relationLoaded('bookmarks')) {
        return $this->getRelationValue('bookmarks');
    }

    // Get the relation from the cache, or load it from the datasource and set to the cache
    $bookmarks = Cache::rememberForever($this->getBookmarksCacheKey(), function () {
        return $this->getRelationValue('bookmarks');
    });

    // Set the relation to the current instance of model
    $this->setRelation('bookmarks', $bookmarks);

    return $bookmarks;
}
```

Comment: This is most complete answer, great work. However, additional !$this->relationLoaded check is redundant as you're already checked it before assigning value to $bookmarks variable.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for... thank you!

Comment: Thanks! However, as at Laravel 9 at least, `if ($this->relationLoaded('bookmarks')) {` block is not required as the `getRelationValue` method checks this anyway

Comment: This is a great solution, with the amendment made (relationLoaded check removed) and a TTL added to the cache - especially for something like bookmarks, but also just to allow the purge system a chance to tidy up when you stop using this or rename it one day.

Comment: It is a very good an complete answer, but IMO a nice addition to `clearBookmarksCache()` method would be this line:

`$this->unsetRelation('bookmarks');`

Otherwise, the previously retrieved value is still available as `$this->bookmarks` and will not be re-fetched from DB. The app might be confused.

Answer (score 6):

You can't store a relationship in the cache. You need to cache the actual data retrieved from the database. So you'll have something like this:

```
public function roles()
{
    return \Cache::remember('user_' . $this->id . '_roles', 10, function()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Role')->get()->toArray();
    });
}
```

And now you have to access it as a method, not a property, because it's not returning a relation anymore (and Eloquent would throw an exception):

```
$user->roles();
```

Now you should get an array as you want.

Comment: But is that a prober way? I guess the has Many relation always has to return "hasmany" property?...

Comment: If you want to make it seamless to get the cached results of a relation this is just fine. The `roles` method is not required to return a relation object. But if you want to use the relation in some places without the caching, you can have a `roles` method returning a regular relation, and another method for example `cachedRoles` that returns the cached data. This should make it easier to see the distinction.

Comment: I get an error when trying to use this code. This is what I get `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on array`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cache user together with its roles you can do it this way:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->load('roles');
Cache::put('users_'.$user->id, $user, 10);
```

I don't know why, but you need to use `load` here instead of `with`. If you used `with` you would get error that you cannot cache `PDO` instance.

Comment: It works that way because you are now doing 'lazy eager loading'. You are loading the related models of an already fetched eloquent model.

Comment: How would you convert it back to User model having roles relationship?