# Laravel: How to cache the data retrieved from a relationship of a model?

Tags: laravel, caching, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

There is a model `Country` and relation `translations` as follows

```
<?php

namespace Modules\User\Entities;

use Astrotomic\Translatable\Translatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Modules\Core\Traits\Rememberable;
use Modules\User\Entities\Sentinel\User;

class Country extends Model
{
    use Rememberable;
    use Translatable;

    protected $table = 'countries';
    public $translatedAttributes = ['name'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'code',
        'weight',
    ];

//    protected $rememberCacheTag = 'countries';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'country_id');
    }

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('lang', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->whereHas('translations', function (Builder $q) {
                $q->where('locale', App::getLocale());
            });
        });
    }

    public function translations(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany($this->getTranslationModelName(), $this->getTranslationRelationKey());
    }
}
```

I need to cache the data of the `translations` relation. I have tried the following so far that taken from [Link](https://laravel.io/forum/04-25-2014-caching-relationships-and-table-data)

```
$c = Country::with([
    'translations' => function($q){
        $q->remember(600);
    }
])->remember(600)->find($this->country_id);
```

and this solution too

```
public function translations(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany($this->getTranslationModelName(), $this->getTranslationRelationKey())->remember(600);
}
```

But I got the error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::remember()

How can I cache the data retrieved from a relation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cache Eloquent Relationship query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844611/cache-eloquent-relationship-query)

Comment: @geertjanknapen I already saw this before. Doesn't work

Comment: Why not cache the full query then?

Comment: @geertjanknapen Please post your suggestion as an answer

Comment: I did, see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cache the entire query, since just caching the relation does not work. (At least out of the box, unsure if you can 'hack' it)

So, using Laravel Cache, it becomes as follows;

```
$countryId = $this->countryId;
return Cache::remember("<your_cache_key>", 600, function() use ($countryId) {
   return Country::with(['translations'])->find($countryId);
});
```

If you are using Redis/Predis (or anything else that supports cache tagging), you can even add cache tags to it;

```
$countryId = $this->countryId;
return Cache::tags([<array_of_cache_tags>])->remember("<your_cache_key>", 600, function() use ($countryId) {
   return Country::with(['translations'])->find($countryId);
});
```

In the example `<your_cache_key>` could be something along the lines of `"country_translations:{$countryId}"`.

`<array_of_cache_tags>` could be something like `["country", "translations"]`